# youtube views count increasing

Tags: youtube

I added youtube video in my website, i have question that is that possible that wen we watch the video in the website and the view of the video youtube get increased.

Need Urgent reply. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can I ask how this is urgent?

Comment: its urgent as i need to do implement in my website

Answer (score 3):

I think you can get the answer from [here](http://www.atlantaanalytics.com/practicing-web-analytics/how-does-youtube-video-view-count-work/):

> YouTube video count WILL increment when:
>
> 1. You watch a video on youtube.com, as long as you don’t reload the video a bazillion times (particularly as it approaches 308 views).
> 2. You watch an embedded video (using YouTube’s own HTML5 or Flash player) on another domain that requires you to hit play.
>
> YouTube will NOT increment video count when:
>
> 1. You watch an embedded video in a player that has autoplay enabled (video begins playing immediately on page load).
> 2. You watch a video that is loaded through a proprietary player via the YouTube API.