# Embedded youtube video with "autoplay=1". Does it count towards views?

Tags: algorithm, youtube, view, embed, autoplay

I can cause an embed youtube video to begin playing automatically using "autoplay=1"
When a user views the embedded video does it count towards my views count?

I have attempted to test but had inconclusive results. Viewed embedded videos to not appear to consistently convert to views even when play is manually clicked.

My tests have been from a single machine and IP which may be the problem? Browser session does not seem to be relevant.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying I didn't nerf it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's been some discussions regarding this topic. Here's a thread with some contradictory answers:

[Does the views in the embed player count?](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/CHQ4juqTbNw)

And here's an article about an official response from Youtube claiming that autoplay views *does not count*:

[Youtube Says Autoplay Don't Count](http://gigaom.com/2008/07/23/youtube-says-autoplays-dont-count/)

Here's another one that claims that embedded videos with autoplay doesn't count:

[How does YouTube video view count work?](http://www.atlantaanalytics.com/practicing-web-analytics/how-does-youtube-video-view-count-work/)

(found through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11963843/645270) SO answer)

Note 1: Note that there seems to exist "cheats" and bugs, but Youtube claims to be working to prevent it. This means that, if you're using their API in a regular way, your autoplay views *probably* doesn't count.

Note 2: The above note is simply Youtube's official statement. Who knows what's really going on. Some people (including you, OP) are getting mixed results.

The bottom line is, don't count on it (pun intended).

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: **NO**

I found this official documentation on the subject (however it's regarding the [Custom gadget development guidelines](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1727240#Video))

> Rule of Thumb:
>   Any time a user initiates a playback using the native player controls, that playback should count. Using an API method to PLAY a video does not count. BUT, you can use cueVideoById and then have the user click a native built in play button and it will count.
>
> Views will NOT be counted if:
>   The user initiates playback via an API method like playVideo or loadVideoById
>   The video autoplays via the autoplay parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the attribute "enablejsapi=1" . This will increase the view count in youtube.com site

Comment: Any reference, please?

Comment: This is false. Autoplaying video even with enablejsapi=1 and starting by js doesn't increase counter.

Answer (score 1):

No. It was a long search, but the answer seems to be hidden here. Follow the link to check it out.

[image: Youtube Embed Help]

Taken from here.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en&ref_topic=3014330