# Will plays via YouTube API register as plays on the site?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

This is a fairly basic question I think.  If a site uses the YouTube API to embed videos on it, will plays to that video also register as plays on the YouTube site itself, or are those plays only counted for people that actually play the video on YouTube.com?

I searched through google and Youtube docs, but didn't see anything relevant, but I could have missed seeing it.

Comment: This seems like something you could test  by yourself pretty easily.

Comment: @csm_dev If it was already set up somewhere to properly test, yes possibly.  However, now it's out here for the world to see and answered in case anyone else has the question and not the means to quickly test it thanks to Janis...That is, after all, the purpose of Stackoverflow, is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They would count as normal plays via YouTube website if you use official [IFrame player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) for embedding.

> Note: A playback only counts toward a video's official view count if
>   it is initiated via a native play button in the player.

However, note if autoplay is enabled, views will not increase.
See here: [Embedded youtube video with "autoplay=1". Does it count towards views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215489/embedded-youtube-video-with-autoplay-1-does-it-count-towards-views).