# How does YouTube play a video on page load?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

YouTube's homepage displays video thumbnails and metadata underneath. When I click on a thumbnail or title of any video, a new page is loaded and the video starts autoplaying. How does YouTube do this while also updating view count for a video?

According to the documentation, a video's official view count is only counted when the native play button in the player is clicked:

[image]

Comment: As the document stated, `autoplay` is not counted as a view count. This was also stated in this [quora question](https://www.quora.com/Do-videos-that-autoplay-increase-a-videos-view) and related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18216005/5995040) which has some important links that will support autoplay does not count as a view. Hope this helps.

Comment: I know that autoplay is not counted as a view count; I pointed this out in my question. I'm asking how YouTube.com autoplays a video on page load while still incrementing view count.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible, can you show us what you have started? Or codes you have tried? If there is no effect on the view count when you autoplay the video when the new page loaded then it is a expected behavior (as it is already described in the document ). The only possible workaround is not setting the video to autoload and let the users click the play video to it to be considered as an official view count.

Comment: I don't have any code, I'm just wondering how youtube.com does it so I can do the same thing.